# macOS users: PDF looks fuzzy in pdf-tools in emacs

Tags: macos, emacs

For all Mac users that have emacs installed, I have successfully installed pdf-tools but the PDF files looks fuzzy. Has anyone managed to increase the resolution?

In case it helps, I have a macOS Catalina (version 10.15.4)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do all PDFs look fuzzy or just bitmap ones (scanned pages e.g.)? Do other PDF viewers have the same problem?

Comment: All the other PDF viewers work perfectly fine (Preview and Skim), but when using pdf-tools in Emacs the files look fuzzy. I thought maybe pdf-tools is not very compatible with Mac? I have tried loads of different things, tried different versions of Emacs and it’s always the same story

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
(setq pdf-view-use-scaling t
        pdf-view-use-imagemagick nil)
```

To enable the retina screen support